# Stop Event propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like when i click in a div, it's not trigger the action on the parent div.

My example :

When I click on the ".chosen-container" div, I don't want to trigger the "sort" on the parent div

I tried this, but this doesn't work :

```
$(document).on("click", '.chosen-container', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   e.stopPropagation();

   return false;
});
```

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure it is this event which is propagating, and not another event bound on the parent that fires? if the latter, stopPropagation won't help

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is not this event which is propagating.